# Maven parallel build freezes during IO

Tags: java, maven

We're currently enabling our Maven project (~1000 modules) to be [built in multiple treads](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) (using the `-T` parameter)

During the early experiments, we noticed that no matter how many threads we use (`-T 1C` or `-T 1.5C`), Maven always blocks all threads when any thread is doing IO (e.g. when a thread is installing artifacts to local repository), and that is definitely affecting the overall performance gain which can be achieved by parallel builds.

The machine we're using is having 8 CPU cores, SSD drive, and Maven is having 24GB of heap, so no resource limitations are seen.

Is there a way to tune this to avoid blocking all threads during IO?

Comment: Are you running on a CI solution like Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, but the problem can be seen on my laptop

Comment: Does each of your Jenkins jobs have it's own local cache ?

Comment: Yes, but again the problem can be seen on my laptop
My question is, why does maven blocks all threads while installing an artifact ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `installAtEnd`, `deployAtEnd` of maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin...furthermore why are using `mvn ... install` why not using `mvn clean verify`?